# Why is logging not considering my configurations?

Tags: python, logging

I would like to use the logging Library to print logging messages on the console I am running my script, and in logging files.

However, I am facing two problems :

1) the setLevel function does not seem to work

2) When I print logging messages on the console, it appears that the buffer storing the logging messages of a run is not flushed between two run. How should I do to dispose of a clean StreamHandler?

To solve the first problem, I tried to change the logger level to the minimum (logging.DEBUG), but it doesn't work

To solve the second problem, I already tried the followings:

1) sys.stdout.flush() before declaring "Stream_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)"

2) logger.propagate = False

3) Stream_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

handlers = logger.handlers
for handler in handlers : 
     logger.removeHandler(handler)

4) logging.shutdown()

None of these are successful.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
level = 'DEBUG'

file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler('logging_test.log')
file_log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)

stream_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stream_log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_log_handler)

def add(x,y):
    """Add function"""
    result = x+y
    logger.info('Add result : {}'.format(result))
    return result

def substract(x,y):
    """Substract function"""
    result = x-y
    logger.debug('Substract result : {}'.format(result))
    return result

def multiply(x,y):
    """Multiply function"""
    result = x*y
    logger.warning('Multiply result : {}'.format(result))
    return result

def divide(x,y):
    """Divide function"""
    try:
        result = x-y
        logger.debug('Divide result : {}'.format(result))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        logger.error('Tried to divide by zero')
    else:
        return result


num_1 = 10
num_2 = 5

add_result = add(num_1, num_2)

sub_result = substract(num_1, num_2)

mul_result = multiply(num_1, num_2)

div_result = divide(num_1, num_2)
```

In the console, I get :

- At the first run :

In [3]: runfile('...')

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

- At the second run :

In [4]: runfile('...')

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

- At the third run :

In [4]: runfile('...')

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

2019-09-18 21:56:56,636:WARNING:**main**:Multiply result : 50

- etc.

Why are the logging messages stacking from a run to another?
Why are only the WARNING level messages that are printed?

Answer (score 0):

You've only set the level on your two handlers, not on the logger itself.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')

file_log_handler = logging.FileHandler('logging_test.log')
file_log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_log_handler)

stream_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stream_log_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_log_handler)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Hello Chepner, thank you for your answer.

Indeed, adding "logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)" helps to print out the logging messages.

But why is there a logging.XHandler.setLevel() method if it does not work?
And how could I distinguish handler configurations if I finally have to errase every configurations by setting new configurations to the logger module with logger.setLevel(logging.Y)?
To finish, the second problem, with the superposing printings on the console is not solved...

Comment: A message has to pass through the logger before the handlers decide if they will "react" as well.